# With Image Process change each shape's color to a unique color

Tags: python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have a png with multiple shapes on it that represent fictional geographic locations.  I would like for each of theses locations to render with a different color so that they are easier to process.

I know how to change anything that is x color to y color, but I don't know how to set up the code so that it changes the color of the current shape and then moves on.

```
    if pixelMap[i,j] == white:
        node.append pixelMap[i,j]
        #look at all white pixels connected to current node 1
```

expected result is that I can input an image like this:

https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/404701706820124676/608881289080209408/Asset_2.png

and come out with each shape a unique color.

Answer (score 1):

You are essentially looking for *"flood-filling"* of an area constrained by a boundary, and you can do that with PIL/Pillow's `ImageDraw.floodfill()` method like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

from PIL import Image, ImageDraw
import numpy as np

# Open the image
im = Image.open('map.png').convert('RGB')

# Make all pixels in top-left country into magenta (255,0,255)
ImageDraw.floodfill(im,xy=(40,40),value=(255,0,255),thresh=50)

# Make all pixels in bottom-right country into yellow (255,255,0)
ImageDraw.floodfill(im,xy=(100,100),value=(255,255,0),thresh=50)
```

That gets you this:

[image]

I am not certain what you mean by *"moving on to the next area"*, but I presume you could put the flood fill commands in a loop and keep taking the position of the first white pixel as the seed for the flood filling until there are no more uncoloured (white) pixels left. To do that, I would convert the PIL Image into a Numpy Array and find the coordinates of the white pixels like this:

```
# Convert PIL Image to Numpy Array
n = np.array(im)

# Get X,Y coordinates of all remaining white pixels
y, x = np.nonzero(np.all(n==[255,255,255],axis=2))
```